# Flutter - Json.decode changes order of data

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter and Dart and I have this problem where the order of items in a json change when I use json.decode. I want to keep the insertion order.

Here is an example of output where the first is the object as it came before decoding and then after decoding.

```
{"113":"13:37:20","155":"13:38:10","157":"13:38:42","159":"13:39:29","161":"13:39:55","163":"13:40:36","165":"13:40:54","135":"13:41:19","137":"13:41:38","139":"13:42:01","141":"13:42:19","143":"13:42:45","145":"13:43:34","147":"13:44:02","149":"13:44:27","0710":"13:48:28","0730":"13:49:12","0750":"13:49:38","0770":"13:50:13","0800":"13:50:45","0810":"13:51:20","0830":"13:55:09","0870":"13:56:41","0900":"14:04:42","1060":"14:17:49"}
-----------
{113: 13:37:20, 135: 13:41:19, 137: 13:41:38, 139: 13:42:01, 141: 13:42:19, 143: 13:42:45, 145: 13:43:34, 147: 13:44:02, 149: 13:44:27, 155: 13:38:10, 157: 13:38:42, 159: 13:39:29, 161: 13:39:55, 163: 13:40:36, 165: 13:40:54, 1060: 14:17:49, 0710: 13:48:28, 0730: 13:49:12, 0750: 13:49:38, 0770: 13:50:13, 0800: 13:50:45, 0810: 13:51:20, 0830: 13:55:09, 0870: 13:56:41, 0900: 14:04:42}
```

I do that using this code

```
if (jsonResult.isNotEmpty) {
      final jsonData = jsonDecode(jsonResult) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      print('#######');
      print(jsonResult);
      print('-----------');
      print(jsonData);
```

Apparently decode sorts them by key but that is not something I want.

What am I missing?

Comment: JSON "object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value
   pairs", quote from the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.html).  So you can't rely on the order of the keys. If the order is important, you have to use an array.

Comment: Thank you for that. I changed it to an array and now it works, but out of curiosity I will leave the question open to see of anyone else has a different solution using JSON.

Comment: You are welcome, I am not aware of a JSON based solution that's why I haven't posted an answer. But I think it is unlikely based on the RFC 7159.

Comment: Do you really need this data in the original order?